# React CSSTransitionGroup animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-animated

I am trying the following simple show/hide animation and the item does appear and disappear but without any animation:

```
toggleChangePassword = () => {
  this.setState({ showChangePassword: !this.state.showChangePassword })
}

....

<button onClick={this.toggleChangePassword}>Forgot your password?</button>

<CSSTransitionGroup
  transitionName="example"
  transitionEnterTimeout={500}
  transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
  {this.state.showChangePassword && changePassword}
</CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Comment: How are you defining your onEnter and onExit animations properties? In a .css file?

Comment: Do I need to? I thought this lib comes with the CSS. They have no documentation about the CSS.

Comment: What's the name of the npm package you're using?  I'm assuming you're using `'react-transition-group'` which is the package that react-doc encourages people to use for animations in react.